Getting percent of row total in looker studio pivot table
I'm trying to get the percentage of row total for each cell on this table in looker studio

Is there a way to get row total comparisons instead of overall total? There is no option in the metric properties for row total summarization. I thought maybe I could aggregate by the average of the binary or do a sum/count calculated field, but the result ends up being 100% for any combination other than will 'null'. I don't understand how I'm able to produce the counts but there is no way to translate to % by row.
